# Trying to find float variables in a list with recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, floating-point

I'm trying to write a program that goes through a list using recursion that counts how many float variables are in the list.

```
def recFloatCount(lst):
string = ''
if len(lst) <= 0:
    return  
else:
    if type(lst[0]) == float:
        string = string + str(lst[0])  
recFloatCount(lst[1:])
print(len(string))
```

The way this is supposed to work is that the program will go though the list, add each float to string, then print the length of string. However, when I run the program using

```
recFloatCount([1, 2.0, 3])
```

it returns

```
0
3
0
```

How can I get this so it just prints 1?

Comment: Fix your indentation to match what you're actually running, otherwise we'll have to guess what you're doing.

Comment: without recursion it's quite easy: `sum(isinstance(x, float) for x in lst)`

Comment: The length of `str(2.0)` is 3.  What were you expecting it to be?

Comment: @StephenRauch Thank you, that helped me figure it out. Instead of adding lst[0] to string as a float, I changed it to an integer. You pointing out that the string was 2.0 helped. For some reason I was imaging the string as just one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This task is quite a bad place to use recursion. But lets assume you really need to
2. variable `string` being created "locally" for every function run. So, its empty while running code for `1` and `3`. If you need to *count* floats, string is bad container. You should use integer and pass it down to next calls, so function should accept list and counter state.